# Springboot Keycloak admin CLI Realm Role udpate effective only after application service reboot

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, jhipster, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I am working on keycloak admin CLI with Springboot to update a user's realm role from my web application. The code to update realm role is:

```
public void updateOauthRoles(String userId, Set<String> oldRoles, Set<String> newRoles)
    {
        RealmResource realmResource = keycloak.realm(realm);

        UserResource userResource = usersResource.get(userId);

        List<RoleRepresentation> oauthOldRoles = oldRoles
            .stream()
            .map(r -> realmResource.roles().get(r).toRepresentation())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<RoleRepresentation> oauthNewRoles = newRoles
            .stream()
            .map(r -> realmResource.roles().get(r).toRepresentation())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        userResource.roles().realmLevel().remove(oauthOldRoles);
        userResource.roles().realmLevel().add(oauthNewRoles);
    }
```

after this, I can see the role is updated on Keycloak server side.

eg. I want to update role from ROLE_EXTERNAL_MANAGER(oldRoles) to ROLE_EXTERNAL_OWNER(newRoles), after I call the above function, I can see that role has been updated on keycloak side
[image]

However, if I try to retrive user info through auth token (from the .getAuthorities() part)

```
public User getUserEntityFromAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationToken authToken)
    {
        Map<String, Object> attributes;
        if (authToken instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
            attributes = ((OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authToken).getPrincipal().getAttributes();
        } else if (authToken instanceof JwtAuthenticationToken) {
            attributes = ((JwtAuthenticationToken) authToken).getTokenAttributes();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("AuthenticationToken is not OAuth2 or JWT!");
        }
        User user = getUser(attributes);
        user.setAuthorities(
            authToken
                .getAuthorities()
                .stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .map(authority -> {
                    Authority auth = new Authority();
                    auth.setName(authority);
                    return auth;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toSet())
        );

        return syncUserWithIdP(attributes, user);
    }
```

it still returns me the old role ROLE_EXTERNAL_MANAGER. The only way I fix this is to restart my web application and try to read the role from authtoken (exactly the same token). Then roles will be updated in my web application. Is there a way I can "refresh" the realm role after I add/remove so it can reflect in web application instantly?